# Can we pass an asp.net Model to an action metod by jquery/ajax function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am teaching myself asp.net mvc4, and I wounder if I could pass an asp.net Model to an action method by jquery/ajax function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

On the Javascript side of things, generate a JSON and send it to your Action method.
On this method, you just Deserialize it back to a Model object using, for example, Json.NET.

Oh the other way round, you can just Serialize the Model object into a JSON.

http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC 4 you dont actually "pass" the model to the action method. If you do a form submit the model values will automatically be available to you in the action.

If you want to explicitly call the action in an ajax method then you can pass the individual values as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

U can do it as follows,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/Insert", // Your URL
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```